# Labels are diappearing while zooming in or out

Tags: geoserver

We are using Geoserver 2.10.0. While displaying the labels in the maps, the labels which are there on the border of the tiles(4*4) are not getting displayed properly. the labels can be seen after further zooming in or out(when they fall in the center of the tile and not in the border). in this image you can see the labels are being cut

On zooming further, the labels come properly, as expected

In the first image(1.png), the labels are cut. But in the second image(2.png), we see on zooming further, the labels are coming as expected.

Please help.

Can someone please suggest a solution without using GeoWebCache.

Comment: If you tried uploading images, they're not there. You may want to update your question.